# PT2 behavior of closed loop system

Tags: control-system, pid-controller

In control design often it is assumed that the transfer function of the closed-loop system is similar to a PT2 element (PT2– 2nd order prototype transfer function)

as

$$T(s)=\frac{\omega_0^2}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_0s+\omega_0^2}$$

with damping $$\zeta$$ and characteristic frequency $$\omega_0$$

or in other words having a complex conjugate pair of poles. In the frequency characteristic method and root locus method this desired behavior is used as a design target.

Why is the PT2 behavior actually assumed for the desired behavior of a closed-loop system?

Edit:

It seems that the acronym PT is not as common as I thought, this is a link to a website:

https://hackaday.io/page/4829-identification-of-a-damped-pt2-system

Comment: What does PT2 mean - please add a link to the acronym. Also add a link to the document that states or implies that *in control design it is assumed that the transfer function of the closed-loop system is similar to a PT2 transfer function*

Comment: @Andyaka: I thought PT1, PT2 elements are well known. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Obviously so we'll known that you appear unable to explain

Comment: 2nd order closed loop response is not necessary desired, especially not when underdamped. (the steeper roll-off can be nice, depending on the other things that come with it for a given situation). It may be more a matter of getting a useful approximation. There is very often a dominant pole or pole-pair (if complex conjugate). The form in the question can express both of these. In general tho, IMO we can't assume 2nd order response without justification. Also no zeros in that form, which is often not the case, but complicates matters so leave that aside for now.